# Joined 2 tables together and I need to have the last 3 column's data fields on seperate rows

Tags: sql-server

I have columns like the following:

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Column6|Column7|Column8
```

So Columns 1-5 are part of table1 and columns 6-8 are part of table2. 
Table 2 is basically a continuation of table2 as it has a foreign key to table1.

What I currently have is all of my data fields on one row from column1-8 as follows:

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Column6|Column7|Column8
data   |data   |data   |data   |data   |data   |data   |data   |
```

However this is not what I want I need to have the last three columns(6-8) on separate rows like this:

```
Column1|Column2|Column3|Column4|Column5|Column6|Column7|Column8
data   |data   |data   |data   |data   |       |       |       |
       |       |       |       |       |data   |data   |data   |
       |       |       |       |       |data   |data   |data   |
       |       |       |       |       |data   |data   |data   |
       |       |       |       |       |data   |data   |data   |
       |       |       |       |       |data   |data   |data   |
       |       |       |       |       |data   |data   |data   |
```

What is the best approah to do this with a SqlServer Query?

EDIT: This is my current query but again it returns everything onto one single row. I need pd.PropertyName, ep.StringValue and ep.IntValue returned on the following rows as long as they are not all null

```
select 
et.ETypeName, 
et.DisplayName, 
et.ElementClassName, 
et.ElementKind,
et.ElementOf, 
et.Description, 
et.WriteToEntry, 
et.WriteToHistory, 
pd.PropertyName, 
ep.StringValue, 
ep.IntValue 
from ettbl as et
 join eptbl as ep on et.ETypeId = ep.ETypeId
 join pdtbl as pd on pd.PId = ep.PId
 order by et.ETypeName, pd.SortOrder, pd.PName
```

Comment: It's hard to tell how your 1 existing row should become 7.  Can update your example to use less generic data?

Comment: Did you check the various operators such as ROLLUP or CUBE? Might be of interest: https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @destination-data I was just trying to illustrate my fields being on one row.  as opposed to certain columns being on the next sequential rows.  Sorry for the confusion.  I have a lot more than 7 rows in my actual table. I was simply trying to illustrate my issue.

Comment: @Rene this is in German

Comment: Whoever downvoted my question, can you please provide a reason so that I may try to correct/edit the OP?

Comment: OK, here once more in english: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
et.ETypeName, 
et.DisplayName, 
et.ElementClassName, 
et.ElementKind,
et.ElementOf, 
et.Description, 
et.WriteToEntry, 
et.WriteToHistory, 
NULL as PropertyName, 
NULL as StringValue, 
NULL as IntValue 
from ettbl as et
UNION ALL
select 
NULL AS ETypeName, 
NULL AS DisplayName, 
NULL AS ElementClassName, 
NULL AS ElementKind,
NULL AS ElementOf, 
NULL AS Description, 
NULL AS WriteToEntry, 
NULL AS WriteToHistory, 
pd.PropertyName, 
ep.StringValue, 
ep.IntValue 
from ettbl as et
 join eptbl as ep on et.ETypeId = ep.ETypeId
 join pdtbl as pd on pd.PId = ep.PId
 order by ETypeName, SortOrder, PName
```

This query should work, however it will depend on the relationships between your tables. You could see duplicates if some relationships are one-to-many.

Comment: This will only work if only one row from table1 is returned.

Comment: @TabAlleman The user didn't provide a where clause or joining key either, so this query is at best, a starting point. Your answer is superior in trying to find the real reason behind this question.

Comment: @ArthurD I have edited my OP.  Does that help at all?

Comment: @Tim yes, Please run my latest query and see if the results match what you're looking for. You can use CTRL-F to find and replace `NULL` with blanks, such as `''` if you don't want to see `NULL`

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I can make this work with my tables.

Answer (score 1):

The BEST approach is to handle this in the presentation layer.

However, treating your question as academic, one way you can do this in SQL is to get a ROW_NUMBER partitioning over all the columns that you want to leave blank after the first row, and use a CASE expression to return an empty string instead of the actual column data if the ROW_NUMBER is greater than 1.

Comment: I agree that presentation layer is by far the best place to handle this.  However, I am to put this into a csv file and I have been instructed that the last 3 columns which are from another table be on the following rows for however many match the ep.ETypeId.  I guess for an easier to read/write csv file

Comment: As far as your solution would that lead to any skipped rows further on in my data or would it simply leave empty strings in those columns, fill in the rest and then move on to the next row to populate the rest of the columns the same way?

Comment: My suggestion would not result in any skipped rows.   It will populate the first 5 columns whenever they change, and will fill them with empty strings the rest of the time.